# script won't load with infinite scroll and masonry

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll

I am using this script to get random background colors on my posts. It works fine when you load the page but when the new posts load the script doesn't work.

This is the code I used for the random background colors:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.entry').each(function () {
        var hue = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor((256-199)*Math.random()) + 200) + ',' + (Math.floor((256-199)*Math.random()) + 200) + ',' + (Math.floor((256-199)*Math.random()) + 200) + ')';
        $(this).css("background-color", hue);
    });
});
```

This is the infinite scroll / masonry code:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var $content = $('#posts');
    $content.masonry({itemSelector: '.entry'}),
    $content.infinitescroll({
        navSelector : 'div#pagination',
        nextSelector : 'div#pagination a#nextpage',
        itemSelector : '.entry',
        loading: {
            finishedMsg: '',
            img: 'http://static.tumblr.com/vk03xn8/Grsnluvip/ajax-loader.gif'
        },
        bufferPx : 600,
        debug : false,
    },
    function( newElements ) {
        var $newElems = $( newElements );
        $newElems.hide();
        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
            $content.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true, function(){
                $newElems.fadeIn(1300);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

How can I combine both so that script works when new posts load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your random color background logic in a function, call it on document ready and once new element are added. This could be for example:

```
function randColor() {
    $('.entry:not(.randomized)').each(function () {
      var hue = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor((256-199)*Math.random()) + 200) + ',' + (Math.floor((256-199)*Math.random()) + 200) + ',' + (Math.floor((256-199)*Math.random()) + 200) + ')';
      $(this).addClass('randomized').css("background-color", hue);
  });
}

// doc ready
$(randColor);
```

And in appended callback:

```
$content.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true, function(){randColor(); $newElems.fadeIn(1300);} );
```

Comment: it runs the script when new posts load but now it doesn't load on the first set of posts until the next set load

Comment: @Pablo But have you set: `$(randColor);`??? Because this calls method on doc ready